# PYQT Widget in Layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am Trying to figure out how to get a widget centered and fully shown in a layout.

The following code creates the widget and places it in the vertical layout just fine. However the widget is not centered in the layout and the bottom half is cut off.

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
FRM_widget = gsFRMPlaybackWidget.Ui_Form()
FRM_widget.setupUi(widget)
g_mainWindow.verticalLayout_mode.addWidget(widget,0)
```

The vertical layout is empty initially. I add a widget to it, then remove it later. The widget that is added is based on a combox selection. The contents and size of the widget will be different.

It will create the widget from another .py file (which is imported).

Is there some option for the vertical layout that I need to set? Is there an option for the widget I need to set?

Couldn't find anything that worked online.

Comment: Has your layout been applied to a widget? Since it's cutting off the inserted widget, it sounds like the parent isn't expanding to accommodate.

Comment: how do I do that? I figured that adding the widget to the layout would automatically do that?

Comment: @lr100 provide a [mre]

Comment: You're adding a child widget into the layout, so the layout manages that child. Then you need to apply the layout to a parent widget using QWidget::setLayout. Then the parent will resize itself to accommodate the contents of the layout.

Comment: The flow of layouts are MainWindow->verticalLayout1->verticalLayout2->this widget

Answer (score 0):

I got to work. 
In the gsFRMPlaybackWidget code (or designer) I had to set the forms layout to horizontally:expanding and vertically:preference for what I needed.